# Possible settings for test release pipeline after successfully run build pipeline in CI/CD in Azure devops server

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a automation test project in azure devops in which I have created a test plan. And there is two pipeline, one is for development and other one is for testing. The testing code trigger the development code for test the test plan. but when I create the pull requests then build pipeline run successfully but release pipeline shows the artifacts error([error]Failed to create Release artifact directory 'C:\azagent\A5_work\r1\a'). How to resolve this error?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [repro]. We do not have enough information to provide an answer. You will likely need to include the release pipeline YAML configuration.

Comment: Please add a variable `system.debug` and set its value to `true` in your release pipeline. Then trigger the release again and share the complete error message in the debug log.